# mapcar but return non-nil element only

Tags: mapping, filtering, sequences

Is there a function that applies a transformation to a sequence and returns only the non-nil values?

Right now I am using the following (as an example):

```lisp
(seq-filter #'identity (mapcar (lambda (x) 
                                 (when (< x 3) (+ x 5)))
                               '(1 2 3 4 5 6)))
```

Or through `dolist`

```lisp
(defun mapcar-true (func list)
  (let (value)
    (dolist (elt list value)
      (when-let ((trans (funcall func elt)))
        (setq value (append value (list trans)))))))
```

But I feel there must be a more straightforward way.

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `remq` or `delq` to remove `nil` elements from a list (to remove more complex structures, consider `remove` and `delete`, too).

```lisp
(remq nil (mapcar (lambda (x) 
                    (when (< x 3) (+ x 5)))
                  '(1 2 3 4 5 6)))
```

The first example can be also simplified using `flatten-tree` as it will remove empty lists, i.e. `nil`s.

```lisp
(flatten-tree (mapcar (lambda (x) 
                        (when (< x 3) (+ x 5)))
                      '(1 2 3 4 5 6)))
```

Comment: Please indent your example properly. (A guess is that you pasted code that uses TAB chars for indentation. If so, you'll want to convert them to space chars here. `M-x untabify` can do that for you in Emacs.)

Comment: +1. (But I'd say the former is simpler than the latter.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I thought there must be a solution that does not create an intermediate list with nil values (I should've specified this in my original question). But I guess removing nil values is easy enough.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a function that applies a transformation to a sequence and returns only the non-nil values?

Since Emacs 26, you can use `mapcan`:

```el
(mapcan (lambda (n)
          (and (< n 3) (list (+ n 5))))
        (number-sequence 1 6))
```

Alternatively, there's the age-old `mapcar+delq` approach like in [choroba's answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/64120/15748) (`delq` is more commonly used than `remq`, since `mapcar` already returns a fresh list, so there's no need to copy it first).

Which of the two approaches to use usually boils down to personal preference and/or performance profiling.

Personally, I'd submit a feature request via `M-x report-emacs-bug` for such a function to be added to `seq.el`.